# Translating OnClick to OnTouch (or something similiar)?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am new to smart phone development. I am using Delphi Xe5 to create a test application I can port to Android and IPhone.

I have a FireMonkey Mobile Application in which I have a TlistBox on the main form. I want the user to select an item in the list and I then display some information based on their selection in another form.

I currently use the ListBox's OnClick event to do this

However, when testing on devices, it seems that I have to touch it more than once (almost like a double click with a mouse).

Am I suppose to be using some kind of touch event? Gestures?

If so, how would I get the index of the selected item?

Example OnClick event

```
procedure TfrmProjects.lbxProjectsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ShowMessage(IntToStr(lbxProjects.ItemIndex));
end;
```

EDIT:

I have looked at the GestureManager and tied it to the ListBox's Touch property Gesture Manager, but can't seem to find a simple OnTouch

Thanks

Comment: Does the event fire when you touch then release because `OnClick` doesn't usually fire until the mouse button is released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `TListBox`, you simply use the `OnChange` event. There's no `TGestureManager` required; changes to the selection via a tap are automatically routed there:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TListBoxItem;
begin
  Item := ListBox1.Selected;
  if Assigned(Item) then
    ShowMessage(Format('Item %d text is %s', [Item.Index, Item.Text]))
  else
    ShowMessage('No item selected');
end;
```

You might want to spend some time with the Samples that are provided for FireMonkey Mobile. (You can find them from the XE5 item in your Start menu; there's a `Samples` link that opens the folder.) There are two separate folders that are helpful, the `FireMonkeyMobile` and the `MobileCodeSnippets`; both of them contain some good demo projects. There are also several tutorials in the documentation at [Mobile Tutorials](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Mobile_Tutorials%3a_Delphi_Mobile_Application_Development_%28iOS_and_Android%29) in the docwiki at Embarcadero.

Comment: Ill give that a try later today and let you know - thanks Ken

Answer (score 1):

If you find you have to tap it wice after a scroll, but not if there has been no scroll, then this is a bug I logged some while back. `OnClick` should work, but gets broken by a scroll operation, in my experience.

Please refer to [this bug](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=119110) and see if it matches your experience.

Interestingly, just as an aside, there is an almost "vice versa" [bug reported here](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=119109).